# PDF Rendering Gibberish in Browser

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, fonts

I built a PDF in Illustrator, and am linking to it from a web page.  It looks fine in SumatraPDF and in the Windows preview pane, but the browser renders this (just so you know, this is not how I want it to look)

[image]

Is this because I have font embedded?  The only thing that I want to have happen with this is for a couple links on it to be clickable; otherwise, I'd convert it all to outlines.  Is there something I need to do here that I haven't done?

**EDIT**: Here's a weird update about this.  The browser follows the link embedded in the pdf when I click it.  So it has the right data, but the wrong presentation apparently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you are/were using either the Dev or Canary channel of Chrome. There was an experiment running in both channels that was causing this, which has since been reverted in Canary but is still affecting Dev 59.0.3053.X. For the more technical; this experiment enabled the PDFium code to use Skia to render paths instead of Anti-Grain Geometry and caused this font gibberish.

Here is the link to the bug report:
 https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=705039

**UPDATE:** This was fixed in the Dev Channel with update 59.0.3071.X

Comment: That annoying.  I converted it to outlines - thanks for the answer!.